# MarkerClustererPlus: Event when marker is shown / hidden in cluster?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When using MarkerClustererPlus - I would like to hang some code on an event that is triggered when a marker that is in a cluster is shown / hidden by the markerClusterer.

MC+ Doco doesn't seem to indicate such an event.

Looking at the MC+ code it appears that the clusterer uses marker.setMap() and markers don't have a "map_changed" event.

I could add code to the clusterer to trigger an event whenever a marker.setMap is invoked but I'd rather not alter code that works so well - don't want to create a configuration management problem whenever markerClustererPlus is updated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortly after posting the question, I discovered that I could hang an event on marker, 'map_changed'.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'map_changed',
function() { do stuff });
```

I think this is an MVC state change event rather than an explicit marker event (i.e. it isn't defined as a marker event in the documentation).
[(see Google event doco here)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview) and [Google marker event doco here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

The only remaining question is - it would be nice to verify that this is an MVC state change event rather than an undocumented / unsupported marker event that could break or disappear -  How can I do that?